# Samsung Android users claiming they are not getting notifications from my app anymore

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, samsung-galaxy

I have an Android app where a lot of my users are claiming they are no longer receiving push notifications.

I have 2 Android phones for testing (both Motorola) running Android 8.0 and 11.0 and the notifications are working fine for me.

I send my notifications through AWS Simple Notification Service (SNS) using Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Note: I am using the "Cloud Messaging API (Legacy)" Server Key from Firebase to enter into SNS as that's how I understand it works.

All of the users claiming they are not receiving push notifications seem to be using a Samsung Galaxy phone.

Is there any weird peculiarity with the Galaxy phones that you've come across? Do I have to do something different when sending notifications to these phones? Is there something specific about Samsung phones where it's the end user not understanding their settings?

Any advice is helpful. Thank you!

UPDATE:
I updated my Android phone running Android 11.0 to Android 12.0 and my app no longer gives me notifications so whatever the problem is it seems to target Android 12.0

Comment: `Google Cloud Messaging, deprecated April 10 2018, has been deactivated and removed from Google's APIs. For equivalent functionality, use Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)`  source: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging?hl=en

Comment: @Boken thank you for replying. If this is the problem, shouldn't it also not be working on my test phones?

Comment: @Boken Sorry, I am in fact using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) I will update my question

Comment: There are different limitation on Android 12 and 13. It will affect whether the notification will be dropped from you app by the system. For Android 12 you may take a look of the following ref link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#notification_permissions_for_apps_targeting_android_12l_api_level_32_or_lower

Answer (score 0):

Add the notification permission for android 33

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
      //request Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
}
```